# Inline Javascript click function for dynamically added elements with dynamic id's in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Following is my function in which I am appending the div with **HTML** elements dynamically.

```
function setTokenList(){

  if (!(localStorage.getItem("Token") === null)) {

    document.getElementById('showtokens').innerHTML = "";

    var Tokeninfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Token"));

    for(var i=0; i < Tokeninfo.length;i++){
      var a = '<div class="grid-container tokenbackground">';
      a += '<div class="item2 tokenname"><i class="fas fa-share" title="Send Token"></i>';
      a += '<i class="fas fa-minus-circle hideicon" id="'+i+'_hidetoken" title="Hide Token" onclick="hideToken();"></i>';
      a += ' </div>';  
      a += ' </div>';    
      $('#showtokens').append(a);
    }
  }   
}
```

I want to call `onclick="hideToken()` on ***i*** tag to remove that record by passing its id on click. I got the error. When I search similar problems they say that, **Chrome Extensions don't allow you to have inline JavaScript. Assign an ID and use addEventListener to bind the event.**  But how can I use addEventListener to these dynamically created elements? These records will vary every time. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach the event after you attach the element like this

```
function setTokenList(){

  if (!(localStorage.getItem("Token") === null)) {

    document.getElementById('showtokens').innerHTML = "";

    var Tokeninfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Token"));

    for(var i=0; i < Tokeninfo.length;i++){
      var a = '<div class="grid-container tokenbackground">';
      a += '<div class="item2 tokenname"><i class="fas fa-share" title="Send Token"></i>';
      a += '<i class="fas fa-minus-circle hideicon" id="'+i+'_hidetoken" title="Hide Token" onclick="hideToken();"></i>';
      a += ' </div>';  
      a += ' </div>';    
      $('#showtokens').prepend(a);
      $('#'+i+'_hidetoken').on('click', function(){
           $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  }   
}
```

notice the id set on the element, and the css id selector, if needed, you can move the id to the element you want to remove